# After logging in as root I get command not found messages

Tags: linux, sudo

when i give the command `sudo su` or say, `sudo -i`
the terminal logs me in successfully as superuser 
but displays

```
$: command not found
$: command not found
```

Can you help me with how to get rid of this?

Comment: what server type environment is this? Need to know what type of terminal you are running as well. There is a profile or init script running and something is not set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a profile setup for root that is trying to run a command when you switch to root.

DISCLAIMER: Without knowing your environment it is difficult to know where start looking so this may or may not be useful.

I would try the following:

Login as root and cd to your home directory `cd ~/` then type `ls -la` look for any files that have a name like ".bashrc" ".bash_profile" those profile scripts that run every time you fire up a shell for that user. You will need to open that file and see what commands are being ran and then either fix the path to them or remove them.

Comment: ya, this worked for me, I had two extra statements at the end of my .bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `sudo` first before you can use it.

How depends on your linux distribution. [see here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-tutorials-howtos-reference-material/64958-how-install-software-linux.html)

Comment: sudo is installed, you have misread this question.

Comment: he sadi that sudo logs him in fine so it is clearly installed. I think Steve's comment on the question is the important thing (ie that its login scripts generating that error).

Comment: ouch sorry, what shell you are using?